# Setup:static-content:deploy "Error : vendor/tedivm/jshrink/src/JShrink/Minifier"

Tags: magento2, deploy, static-content-deploy

The follwing error occurs during the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US de_DE` execution, but the command continues to work.

> "Error : vendor/tedivm/jshrink/src/JShrink/Minifier"

It's in production mode

How to fix it?

```
#0 vendor/tedivm/jshrink/src/JShrink/Minifier.php(231): JShrink\Minifier->saveString()
#1 vendor/tedivm/jshrink/src/JShrink/Minifier.php(144): JShrink\Minifier->loop()
#2 vendor/tedivm/jshrink/src/JShrink/Minifier.php(110): JShrink\Minifier->minifyDirectToOutput('"no use strict"...', Array)
#3 vendor/magento/framework/Code/Minifier/Adapter/Js/JShrink.php(27): JShrink\Minifier::minify('"no use strict"...')
#4 vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/Minify.php(50): Magento\Framework\Code\Minifier\Adapter\Js\JShrink->minify('"no use strict"...')
#5 vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/Pool.php(77): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Minify->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Chain))
#6 vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(152): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Pool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\Chain))
#7 vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Source.php(105): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->preProcess(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#8 vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/File.php(157): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source->getFile(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#9 vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#10 vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#11
vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticFile.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#12
vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(185): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('js/lib/ace/work...', Array)
#13
vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(132): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile), Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#14 vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(103): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false)
#15 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Service\{closure}()
...
```

Comment: Disable minify from admin and try again.

Comment: it work or not?

Comment: I do not need to disable these settings

Comment: Hi Evgeniy Kapelko , Did you found the solution ?

Comment: Hi, the problem was solved by itself, I can not say what it was connected with.

Comment: Hi, any news about this issue? We use Magento 2.2.4 and have the same Problem with tedivm/jshrink 1.3.2, if you downgrade to 1.3.1 it works fine. composer require "tedivm/jshrink:1.3.1"

Answer (score 1):

Workaround, downgrade to version 1.3.1

```
composer require "tedivm/jshrink:1.3.1"
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me on Magento 2.2.5. Faced this issue when switched to production. Used your solution and it deploys smoothly now. Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

It has now been **fixed** in the version [1.3.3](https://github.com/tedious/JShrink/releases/tag/v1.3.3) released in June 28th.

Update the module with the following command :

```
composer update tedivm/jshrink
```

Answer (score 0):

Still broken for me on Magento 2.2.6 with jshrink 1.3.3 with all third party extensions disabled. Any tips on how to debug?

***UPDATE***

What I've done for now to get things working is just commented out the error output on line 529 of vendor/tedivm/jshrink/src/JShrink/Minifier.php

The commented line looks like the following:

//throw new \RuntimeException('Unclosed regex pattern at position: ' . $this->index);

Now it seems to be minifying both CSS and JS successfully where before when it was throwing the error it wasn't.